# How to see the "hints" or "prompt message" in the visual studio code for matlab (.m) file?

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use Visual studio code to edit my Matlab .m file. After installation and setting of Matlab extension, I can write my m file now. The variables color markers are correct. But I found a problem about the "hints" or "prompts" of my code. I don't know the exact term of it. I just describe it in an example.

When I write some problematic code in Matlab editor, there would be a wavy red line under there. When my mouse cursor stay there, a message pops up, like `invalid syntax at the end of the line`. In the Vscode editor, there is wavy line, too. But it can't show the content of the prompts but only some rhombus symbols. There is a button `Peek Problem` under it. Sorry for lacking pictures here. I am trying to describe the problem in details.

I may need to change the settings but don't know how. Do I need more extensions?  Any suggestions would be appreciate.

Comment: Is it [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gimly81.matlab) you have installed, or a different one? What specific features of the extension are not working as documented?

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. Under your question, I found I really need to check the guide of the installation more carefully. I need to add `"matlab.linterEncoding" : "gb2312"` to the `setting.json`. The special feature is named `code check`. Really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Following prompt of @nekomatic,

add "matlab.linterEncoding" : "gb2312" to the setting.json.